# GCE Container Registry upload slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-compute-engine

since a couple of days the `gcloud docker -- push eu.gcr.io/**` has become very slow. I have tested the following:

1. My connection upload is fine
2. Restarted docker (and Mac)

What could I do? Does someone else have the same problem?

Comment: Experiencing slow upload as well using `gcr.io`. Full stop once. Tried again and it is very slow now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about your poor experience. We aren't aware of any performance issue recently. If you would like us to investigate further, please share with us your project id at gcr-contact@google.com.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the problem is usually caused by local docker. Just restart your docker machine or docker for mac.